# Reverse order of polynomial coefficients of type $\left(r-x\right)^n$

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

I have a simple question.

I have a polynomial defined by
$$
\left(r-x\right)^n = a_0 + a_1 x + ... + a_n x^n
$$

Is there a simple expression if I put the coefficients in reverse order?

$$
a_n + a_{n-1} x + ... + a_1 x^{n-1} a_0 x^n = ?
$$

If $r = 1$ it is easy but for other $r$ I don't know how to do it.

**Edit solution:**
Thanks to the general answer of paul blart math cop, the simple expression with reversed coefficient order is:

$$
x^n \left(r-\frac{1}{x}\right)^n = \left(rx-1\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$, the polynomial with reversed coefficients to $f$ is $x^n f(1/x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your general answer. I edited my question.